# Pandas duplicates groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, duplicates

I've a Pandas dataframe, and some numerical data about some people.
What I need to do is to find people that appare more than one time in the dataframe, and to substitute all the row about one people with one row where the numeric values are the sum of the numeric values of the rows before in some columns, and the minimum of this values in other.
I know how to do the sum using groupby() and sum() but not how to do different thing for the different columns

Example:

```
Names  Column1 Column2 Column3  
John     1        2     2016
Bob      2        3     2011
Pier     1        1     2003
John     3        3     2005
Bob      1        0     2018
```

Have to become:

```
Names  Column1 Column2 Column3  
John     4        5     2005
Bob      3        3     2011
Pier     1        1     2003
```

How can I do?

Comment: Use `groupby` + [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) function.

Comment: Jonh  != John. Are you trying to fuzzy groupby as well?

Comment: Ops, sorry, my fail, now is ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` + `agg` and define specific aggregation functions for each column as a `dict` like:

```
df.groupby('Names').agg({'Column1':'sum', 'Column2':'sum','Column3':'min'})

    Column1 Column2 Column3
Names           
Bob     3     3     2011
John    3     3     2005
Jonh    1     2     2016
Pier    1     1     2003
```