# Pandas dataframe columns after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

here I had solved one my problem:
[Pandas duplicates groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53133174/pandas-duplicates-groupby?noredirect=1#comment93160647_53133174)

Now, after using the command:

```
df.groupby('Names').agg({'Column1':'sum', 'Column2':'sum','Column3':'min'})
```

I have this DataFrame (I create an example):

```
Names Column1 Column2 Column3       
Bob     3     3        2011
John    3     3        2005
Jonh    1     2        2016
Pier    1     1        2003
```

But if I use the command df.columns, 'Names' is not displayed anymore.
what can I do to have the column 'Names' as before using groupby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify parameter `as_index=False` while grouping:

```
df.groupby('Names', as_index=False).agg(
    {'Column1':'sum', 'Column2':'sum','Column3':'min'})

  Names  Column1  Column2  Column3
0   Bob        3        3     2011
1  John        4        5     2005
2  Pier        1        1     2003
```